# How to animate div tag to slide from right to left?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to develope responsive web page. If i click an image, it has to display mymodal div from right to left like slidetoggle (from image has to slide out right to left). 
If i used below method nothings happen (used many other code which was suggested in stackoverflow for similar question). Div tag is moving different locations if i resize webpage. How to achieve this task? Any guidanece pls

```js
$('#mypic').click(function() {

  $('#myModal').toggle("slide", {
    direction: "right"
  }, 700);


});
```

```css
.my-modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #424242;
  color: white;
}

.my-modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.my-modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #424242;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.my-modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 70%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

#closemymodal : {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  align: center;
}

.my_modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  left: -1px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="mypic" height='25' width='25'>

<div id="myModal" class="my_modal" style="overflow:hidden;">

  <div class="my-modal-content">
    <div class="my-modal-header">
      <span class="my_modal_close">&times;</span>
      <h2 style="font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-serif !important; font-size:12px;">Select value</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="my-modal-body">

      <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 25%"><label style="font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-serif !important">select:
          </label></td>
          <td style="width: 75%" id="modalSelectTd">
            <select id="modalValue"> 
            
            <option>  </option> 
            <option>  </option> 
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>
    <div class="my-modal-footer">
      <button id="closemymodal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so, did you include the JQuery UI files ? include them here also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `hover` instead of `click`. If you don't want to use JQueryUI use may used this. **This is pure `css`**. On `hover` of image your div will show up.

```css
.my-modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #424242;
  color: white;
}

.my-modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.my-modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #424242;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.my-modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 70%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

#closemymodal : {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  align: center;
}

.my_modal {
z-index: 99999;
  left: calc(100%);
 position: fixed;
  top: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

#mypic:hover + #myModal {
    left:0px;
  }
```

```html
<img id="mypic" height='25' width='25'>

<div id="myModal" class="my_modal" >

    <div class="my-modal-content">
            <div class="my-modal-header">
                    <span class="my_modal_close">&times;</span>
                    <h2 style="font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-serif !important; font-size:12px;">Select value</h2>
            </div>
              <div class="my-modal-body"> 

                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 25%"><label
                            style="font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-serif !important">select:
                        </label></td>
                        <td style="width: 75%" id="modalSelectTd">
                                <select id="modalValue"> 

                                <option>  </option> 
                                <option>  </option> 
                                </select>
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

          </div>
        <div class="my-modal-footer">
            <button id="closemymodal">Close</button>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check this working snippet.**

```js
$('#mypic').click(function() {

      $('#myModal').toggleClass("open");
 });
```

```css
.my-modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #424242;
  color: white;
}

.my-modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.my-modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #424242;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.my-modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 70%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

#closemymodal : {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  align: center;
}

.my_modal {

  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity:0;
  
  top: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  right: -320px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
       -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
          transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
}
.my_modal.open{
right: 10px;
opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="mypic" height='25' width='25'>

<div id="myModal" class="my_modal" style="overflow:hidden;">

  <div class="my-modal-content">
    <div class="my-modal-header">
      <span class="my_modal_close">&times;</span>
      <h2 style="font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-serif !important; font-size:12px;">Select value</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="my-modal-body">

      <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 25%"><label style="font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-serif !important">select:
          </label></td>
          <td style="width: 75%" id="modalSelectTd">
            <select id="modalValue"> 
            
            <option>  </option> 
            <option>  </option> 
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>
    <div class="my-modal-footer">
      <button id="closemymodal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include ***JQuery UI*** to make it work

[**Working demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/nser2mL8/)

```
$('#mypic').click(function() {

  $('#myModal').toggle("slide", {
    direction: "right"
  }, 700);


});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have already used slide toggle function and that is working...This div only is not working

Comment: Ok but that's the solution to your question

Comment: In application, they have used scrolltabs plugin. If i include this jqueryui , that scrolltabs is not working